# cannot change <label> text color

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, label

My research into the base HTML DOM element says this about any DOM element's "style" property
(from http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp):

```
   "style --    Sets or returns the style attribute of an element"
```

The 'label' tag is a dom element.  And thus it has a 'style' property.  As it points out on the w3schools link
above, all dom elements have a 'style' property.

And in fact, here I'm setting (inline) the 'style' property for a **label** tag -- and this works fine:

```
    <label for="itemImageId" style="color: gray" id="labelForImageUploadID">Item image</label>
```

The label text color is gray at page load time.

Under a certain condition (user has indicated they're ready to select an image to upload) --
I need to show the upload as 'enabled' by changing the initial gray text color of the above  to black.

Do I know I could use a css class for this label's text color and use the 'className' property to dynamically
alter the css class of the  above?  You bet I do.  Tonight though I'm holding this DOM element's feet 
to the fire.  I just have one 'style' attribute to change (text color) and don't want to add a class just for it 
-- what I'm trying here should work according to the docs.

I want to know why I can't use the 'style' property as the DOM says I can -- "get" AND "set" DOM element's 
properties.

Here I'm "set"-ing the 'style' property of my  -- this does NOTHING -- the label text remains gray:

```
    document.getElementById('labelForImageUploadID').style = "color: rgb(0,0,0)";
```

Nor does this change the color from gray to black:

```
    document.getElementById('labelForImageUploadID').style = "color: black";
```

The above code executes (in javascript) *after* the label is already visible on the page, and in response to an onclick event of a button on the form that the label is also a part of.

Is there a bug in the ability to "set" a DOM element's 'style' property?
According to http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp,

```
   "HTMLElement Object

    The following properties, and methods can be used on all HTML elements."

        (other properties here.....)
   "style --    Sets or returns the style attribute of an element"
       (still other properties here......)
```

So why can't I change the  element's 'style' property then in my code above?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<sup>Upon reviewing this answer in 2017, the original example of setting the whole style string does work correctly. I don't know what the problem was,
 but the examples below are still valid approaches.</sup>

---

Setting a style with JavaScript usually follows the following format:

```
document.getElementById("abc").style.[css property name in camel case] = "[value]";
```

- [Basic Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zn5fB/)
- [Event-triggered Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zn5fB/1/)

If using jQuery, it becomes a bit cleaner:

```
// find all elements with the tag name "bar" that are direct 
// descendants of an element with the class name "foo"
$(".foo > BAR").css("color", "red");

// set multiple properties
$(".foo > BAR").css({ color: "red", "background-color": "beige" });
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, that's done it.   It's true W3 is a bit dicey here and there. I have with your help gotten my label's text color to respond correctly -- thanks for your other info also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
label { color: red; }
label span { color: blue; }
```

```html
<label> your Labaet <span>Text</span> </label>
```